# Try to make real time clock using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I've tried for several days to run real time clock task using Angular but when files compile everything stops.I don't where I make my mistake but I'm quite sure that is it TypeScript file. Can you help me?

HTML

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>digitalClock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="">
    <div id="clock">
        here watch needs to work
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

TypeScript

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'web-digital-clock';

  ingOnInit(): void {
    function showTime() {
      var d = new Date();
      var hour = d.getHours();
      var min = d.getMinutes();
      var sec = d.getSeconds();


      var MV = "AM";
      if (hour == 12) {
        MV = "PM";
      }
      if (hour > 12) {
        hour = hour % 12;
        MV = "PM";
      }
      hour = ("0" + hour).slice(-2);
      min = ("0" + min).slice(-2);
      sec = ("0" + sec).slice(-2);


      document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + MV;
    }

    setInterval(showTime, 1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `showTime` function inside the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook?

Comment: Not trying to be mean, but you might want to spend some time following some Angular tutorials first..?

Answer (score 3):

you can use below code to create simple clock application

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription, timer } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  time = new Date();
  intervalId;
  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    // Using Basic Interval
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.time = new Date();
    }, 1000);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    if (this.subscription) {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div>{{ time | date: 'hh:mm:ss a' }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read some tutorials about Angular and Typescript, it will definitely help you.
Happy learning!!!

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
      <div #clock>
          here watch needs to work
      </div>
    `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  public title = 'web-digital-clock';
  @ViewChild('clock', { static: false }) public clock: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.showTime();
    }, 1000);
  }

  private showTime() {
    const d = new Date();
    let hour = d.getHours();
    const min = d.getMinutes();
    const sec = d.getSeconds();

    let MV = "AM";
    if (hour == 12) {
      MV = "PM";
    }
    if (hour > 12) {
      hour = hour % 12;
      MV = "PM";
    }
    this.clock.nativeElement.innerHTML = + ("0" + hour).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + min).slice(-2) + ":" + ("0" + sec).slice(-2) + " " + MV;
  }
}
```